# Generic type that removes fields of a certain type from an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

here is what I want to do:
Suppose I have an object like this:

```
interface X {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  с: string;
  d: number[];
}
```

And I want to delete ALL fields of certain type:

```
type  DeleteFields <X, number> = ... = {c: string, d:number[]}
```

The best I've got is like that:

```
type DeleteFields <T , D> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends D ? "" : T[P];
}

type XNumbersNoNum = DeleteFields <X, number>; // { a: ""; b: ""; с: string; d: number[]; }
```

How can I achieve that behaviour? I tried to play with Omit and etc but didn't get anything better

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBrIN4ChnLgLmRAFcBbAI2gG4dlzCSLrbBBEEIGcwpQBzG3ACYMylKAG0AujQC+WLGACeABxQARCABsIkAGLBNA9gB4AKgBpkAVQB8yALyZaYgNLJQyANYQFAexjITPHYAlwlkCAAPSBBDK2QAfiIIADdoZEJnCUITUJkaLAB6AuRFFWQAJQh2Yg0we0ci3GQ2ZE5uED5C4sFhJnEpLuRZUpRK6tr69S1dfQ1DI1QLRlFrIA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am i missing?

Comment: yes, it works perfectly. I'm trying to get into it, but this `K in keyof T as T[K] extends U ? never : K` looks a bit overwhelming

Comment: I will explain in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will need to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) as you already do, however, we will need to use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to remove the unwanted properties. `key remapping` is a really useful feature that allows not only removing properties but also modifying the keys based on condition:

```
type Getters<Type> = {
    [Property in keyof Type as `get${Capitalize<string & Property>}`]: () => Type[Property]
};
 
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    location: string;
}
 
// type LazyPerson = {
//    getName: () => string;
//    getAge: () => number;
//    getLocation: () => string;
// }
type LazyPerson = Getters<Person>;
```

To remove the properties we will check whether the type of the property extends the type that we want to omit. If the condition is true we will use `never` as a key, otherwise the key itself without modifying it. By changing the key to `never` we actually remove the property, since `never` is empty set, which can't be used as a key:

```
type DeleteFields<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends U ? never : K]: T[K];
};
```

Testing:

```
type DeleteFields<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends U ? never : K]: T[K];
};

// type Result = {
//   с: string;
//   d: number[];
// }
type Result = DeleteFields<X, number>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBrIN4ChnLgLmRAFcBbAI2gG4dlzCSLrbBBEEIGcwpQBzG3ACYMylKAG0AujQC+WLGACeABxQARCABsIkAGLBNA9gB4AKgBpkAVQB8yALyZaYgNLJQyANYQFAexjITPHYAlwlkCAAPSBBDK2QAfiIIADdoZEJnCUITUJkaLAB6AuRFFWQAJQh2Yg0we0ci3GQ2ZE5uED5C4sFhJnEpLuRZUpRK6tr69S1dfQ1DI1QLRlFrIA)

Comment: thank you! totally forgot about this "as" trick P.S. `Add` from your course seems even more interesting))

Comment: @BorisBorais Which course :0? What Add :D?

Comment: Oh, you mean Sum

Comment: yep, I went to source to get into it, confused with another variable.  Can't understand anything but seems quite thrilling